# Create user/pass placement

Tags: username

In a process of setting up a profile the information is very generic up front. However, once the user gets to a point of real interest we ask them to create a username and password.

My question is this: On the information screen where the user types in their name, address, phone, email, etc is it best to have the user/pass above this information or below this information right before they see the "Save & Continue" button?

Answer (score 4):

Your question is very generic, so my answer might not fit, but:

I'd say you should get the minimum possible data to get the user started - keeping the funnel as short and easy as possible will maximize the % of people who complete it and sign up.

So my advice would be to only require user/pass and after they have already completed this step to move on... if they've signed up, you already have a channel back to them to help them through the rest of the process, and when you ask for the information in context (when the user understands why they need to provide it), chances are the responses will be much more positive.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a right answer here. If you follow convention you ask for a username at the top and for a password at the bottom of the form. It might work in your situation or it might not work in your situation.
You could do an AB test and see which form converts the most visitors.